Using Google Drive API v3 with Python, how to list all pages that are under vnd.google-apps.site file?
I am currently using
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file.get("id"), mimeType="text/plain")

to request a vnd.google-apps.site file from a Google Drive, and then importing it as a .txt file. Problem is that the whole site is then downloaded as a big .txt file, but I would like to have each page as its own .txt file. Requesting the file results in a big .txt, how do I list the subpages instead?
Edit:
I have a Google Sites website. I want to save every page on the said website as a separate .txt file. Said website is password protected, so scraping the content with Selenium is out of question, since I want to download the data periodically without any user interaction. Google Drive API supports importing their sites elements into .txt files, and I can do that. Problem is that the whole website is saved into one file, whereas I need one file per page. Hopefully this clears up my problem!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
